# How can I play Battlefield 4 in windowed mode?

Tags: battlefield-4

I'm trying to play Battlefield 4 on my PC but I don't want it to take up the entire screen. How do I do that? I remember having the same problem with Battlefield 3 and I forgot how I solved the problem. I called the customer service number for Battlefield 3 and they told me something like shift + return or ctrl + return or some combination of keys that I've forgotten.

Anyone know the solution?

Comment: Are there no in game settings so that you can adjust the resolution and other things of the game?

Comment: @PythonNovice I'm a dummy. There is an option in the settings to put the game into "windowed" mode vs fullscreen which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @RyanA. Good that you found it. Was going to say that if they didn't have that option it would be dumb. haha. well have fun playing.

Comment: There is a performance impact for running games in a windowed mode. I'm not saying you shouldn't do this but feel you should be made aware of this in the event it's not occurred to you.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible through the graphic settings ingame.

Sorry, that I have my German Battlefield 4 now enabled, but I'll translate the important words for you.
Ingame you may press ESCAPE to go into the menu. There you go to "Settings/Options/Preferences" and then onto the graphics tab. You'll see this extract:

[image: Graphics settings menu]

Two white highlighted areas:

1. In the tab menu on the top: I won't translate this for you, this is homework.
2. "VOLLBILD-MODUS": Translates to "fullscreen mode". There we go!

In that second highlighted menu, you'll have three options for now:

- **Fullscreen**: Guess what!
- **Windowed**: Window mode, as you may wish it. You'll have the game in a seperate window.
- **Borderless window**: I guess you'll love it. The screen is a seperate window, but it has it's borders cut off. So it fits over your screen, just like fullscreen does, but it is in window state so that you can ALT+TAB out quickly, for example.

**HINT:** If you want to play with these settings, I recommend you to go to the TEST RANGE. There you can test out every vehicle and weapon - and settings when not online on competitive servers.

[image: Test Range on the web-browser page of Battlefield 4]

**NOTE:** Remind, that if you change settings in the Test Range, your computer may have a slightly better performance as there are 63 soldiers less in the field as usual. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's ALT + Enter. It's been around since Windows 3.11

Comment: Since Windows 1 even, I think. It was the toggle for full screen or windowed for the DOS command box.